# CSS Crop only height of image - Object Fit

Tags: html, css

I am looking to crop only the height of the image (without affecting the width - so that any image with height over 600px is cropped). My original image dimensions is 1200px x 800px.

In my example I want the image to become 1200px x 600px. I am using this code:

HTML

```
<div class="container"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/Kong.jpg"></div>
```

CSS

```
.container img {
    max-height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

However, this code also adjusts the width of the image downwards. How can I crop only the height of the image with CSS?

I would also like the image to be cropped in the center (not bottom). The solution also needs to be responsive for all devices.

Comment: set .container overflow: hidden, and its height 600px

Comment: Here's an example: https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/gOdEBKW (for images that are 600 wide and 400 high).

Comment: If I use, overflow: hidden; it works but I would like the image to be cropped in the center - not the bottom

Comment: I tried using this but it's not responsive...